# Can I add an IAP without releasing a new build?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Hello I had to fix an IAP id after my iOS app was approved and published.
The app was pointing to IAP with id "MyIAP1" but the id on the AppStore was "MyIAPABC".
This obviously wasn't working... since the App was looking for a non existant IAP ID.

So to avoid releasing a new App build, I've created a new IAP on the AppStore with ID "MyIAP1", the one available in the published App. The IAP is working correctly when I run the App from Xcode but it is not working on production. Do I need to release a new build to somehow enable new IAP products on production? (even if the code is exactly the same of the previous build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can since you have already submitted IAP before.

> Note: If you have already submitted an in-app purchase with your app,
> and you decide to add additional in-app purchases later, you can do so
> without submitting an app version.

ref: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/?lang=en#/dev1986a0e5c